# What is the ideal way to initialize Guice injections from Mule?

Tags: mule, guice

Mule config has built in support for Spring beans, so it is easy to initialize spring beans from mule context. How do we achieve same using Guice?

Answer (score 1):

Guice support is going away: https://www.mulesoft.org/jira/browse/MULE-7779

> Guice module needs to be deprecated in 3.6 so that we can remove it in Mule 4.

If you persist in using it despite this warning, then here is an example of how it's done:

```
<guice:object classBinding="org.mule.module.guice.BananaServiceInterface"/>
```

See: https://github.com/mulesoft/mule/blob/mule-3.x/modules/guice/src/test/resources/guice-service-lookup-config.xml

Comment: Thanks David. Any reason why Mule is removing this module? If we don't go this way, what is the other best way to use Guice with Mule?

Comment: No idea why it's going away. Mule is built upon Spring so if you could use Spring, it would be more natural. Otherwise, there are Spring-Guice bridges, like https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-guice, but I don't know if they're any good.